# SocketProtocolError issue on Android emulator for React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, rest, react-native, mobile

My app was working properly, suddenly the below issue started coming, I have not made any changes for login, tried all possible ways I came across on google

Error: 
SocketProtocolError {name: "SocketProtocolError", message: "Socket hung up", code: 1006,

I am unable to login to the app